# How to display data from hash in react native?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, hashmap

Data:

```
{
    “services”:[
        {id: 1, title: ”title 1”},
        {id:3, title:”title 3”},
        {id:4, title:”title 4”}
    ],

    “Blogs”:[
       {id:2 title:”title 2”},
       {id:5, title:”Services”}
    ]
}
```

I want to display this data on screen as

```
services : 
            id: 1, title: ”title 1”
            id:3, title:”title 3”
            id:4, title:”title 4”

Blogs : 
          id:2 title:”title 2”
          id:5, title:”Services”
```

I wrote the code below but then I got the key value but not the array of that key.

```
{
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) 
    {
        return (    
            <Text>{key}</Text>     
        )
    })
}
```

suggest any solution if anyone knows it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `services.map((item, i) => {return (    
            <Text>{item}</Text>     
        )` try like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render it like so:

```
{Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{`${key} :`}</Text>
    <View style={styles.shiftLeft}>
      { value.map(({ title, id}) => <Text key={id}>{`id: ${id}, title: "${title}"`}</Text>)}
    </View>
  </View>
))}
```

[Here's](https://snack.expo.io/HJjgVnzIQ) a demonstration on Expo.

It renders like so:

[image: example picture rendering as asked]

If needed, the `styles.shiftLeft` is simply:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  shiftLeft: {
    marginLeft: 15,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) for Data iteration. You just need to pass Data object to in this flatlist and it will automatically make a loop. Let me know if you need any other help.